# How to get static const int 3d array length in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I want to get static const int 3d array length in cocos2dx.

I defined 3d array in .h file.

My array is

```
static const int LEVEL[][15][7]=
  {
          /*L1*/{{1,1,20,30},{1,0,35,70},{1,1,65,70},{1,0,80,30}},
          /*L2*/{{1,0,15,33 },{1,0,34,83 } ,{1,1,15,62 },{1,1,34,13 },{1,1,61,83 },{1,1,79,33 } ,{1,0,61,13},{1,0,79,62 }},
          /*L3*/{{1,1,17,26 },{1,1,17,67 } ,{1,1,47,8 },{1,1,47,84 },{1,1,78,26 },{1,1,78,67 },{1,0,27,46 },{1,0,38,26 },{1,0,38,66 },{1,0,57,26 },{1,0,57,66 },{1,0,68,46 } },
          /*L4*/{{1,1,8,31 },{1,1,34,31 } ,{1,1,8,66 },{1,1,34,66 },{1,1,75,11 },{1,1,75,49 } ,{1,1,75,84 },{1,0,21,11 },{1,0,21,49 },{1,0,21,84 },{1,0,62,31 },{1,0,88,31 },{1,0,62,66 },{1,0,88,66 }},
          /*L5*/{{1,1,39,26 },{1,1,39,61 } ,{1,1,9,44 },{1,1,57,6 },{1,1,57,81 },{1,1,87,44},{1,0,22,16},{1,0,22,71},{1,0,57,34},{1,0,57,53},{1,0,72,26},{1,0,72,61}},
          /*L6*/{{1,0,14,34 ,0,0},{1,0,30,14,0,0 } ,{1,0,62,14,0,0 },{1,0,86,49,0,0 },{1,1,30,54 ,0,0},{1,1,46,34 ,0,0} ,{1,1,62,54, 0,0},{2,1,16,79,3,70}},
          /*L7*/{{2,1,20,11,3,64},{8,0,20,83,4,64},{1,1,61,34,0,0},{1,1,80,30,0,0},{1,1,88,57,0,0},{1,0,32,37,0,0},{1,0,40,65,0,0},{1,0,59,61,0,0}},
          /*L8*/{{2,1,11,40,3,24,0 },{3,1,47,5,4,24,0 },{8,1,58,40,4,24,0},{3,1,47,65,3,24,0} ,{4,0,28,10,1,10,315},{4,0,58,25,1,15,45},{4,0,28,75,1,15,45},{4,0,57,60,1,20,315}}
};
```

How can I get this array length?

Comment: When you say "length", what do you mean by that? Please elaborate.

Comment: i want to break all the array element

if i select L1 array it means
L1=>{{1,1,20,30},{1,0,35,70},{1,1,65,70},{1,0,80,30}}
than use first array element {1,1,20,30}
and than knows this array element size and than each element allocate to x,y,rad,color

please described how can i use this array for level structure

Comment: Arrays are fixed size. The inner dimension (in your case) is *always* 7 integers. Even if you initialize with less values there will always be 7 integers in the innermost array. If you want variable number of entries, then you should use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 0):

Just like C-strings always terminate with `\0`, you can add a final (terminator) element of {0}, which you can use to count the length.